# c# MS Access SELECT SQL query with a Constant

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, union

I'm searching two different tables for anything that contains the string that the user typed in.

I need to, however, define which table the record was retrieved from.

In the example below, it could be something as simple as placing a constant field in the query, such as `TYP` and in my c# code I will note that:

When `TYP=0` -> it means it came from the table tbl_parts

When `TYP=1` -> it means it came from the table tbl_kits

I'm not quite sure how to even accomplish this. How would I insert a constant field (where that field is always the same value in the query)? Or is there another better way?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
 SELECT ID, PART_NUMBER, DESCRIPTION 
 FROM tbl_parts WHERE (
      PART_NUMBER LIKE @SEARCH OR
      DESCRIPTION LIKE @SEARCH
 )
 UNION
 SELECT ID, KIT_NUMBER, DESCRIPTION
 FROM tbl_kits WHERE (
      KIT_NUMBER LIKE @SEARCH OR
      DESCRIPTION LIKE @SEARCH
 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple enough.  Just include the column in the query:

```
SELECT 'parts' as which, ID, PART_NUMBER, DESCRIPTION 
FROM tbl_parts
WHERE PART_NUMBER LIKE @SEARCH OR DESCRIPTION LIKE @SEARCH
UNION ALL
SELECT 'kits' as which, ID, KIT_NUMBER, DESCRIPTION
FROM tbl_kits
WHERE KIT_NUMBER LIKE @SEARCH OR DESCRIPTION LIKE @SEARCH;
```

Note:  I changed `UNION` to `UNION ALL`.  You should only use `UNION` when you specifically want to incur the overhead of removing duplicates.  Because the table names are different, there are no duplicates between the tables.

Comment: This is perfect. I never knew about the `as [TYPE]` command. Thank you very much! I will accept this answer once the time-limit is up!